# React Hook update not changing child component's style

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have attempted to solve this for a few weeks and just can not understand what is wrong. I would like to toggle the background color of a button. My component levels are App --> LabAssign --> Test. I am updating the fetched data in App with:

```
setFetchedSamples(fetchedSamples.map(sample => sample.labid === id ? {...sample, status: newStatus, [field]: newTestStatus} : sample))
```

This then re-renders the component LabAssign:

```
import React from 'react'
import Test from 'Components/Buttons/Test'
import Icon from 'Components/Buttons/Icon'

const AssignLab = (props) => {

  let sample = props.sample
  let unassigned = '#d3d3d3d'
  let assigned = props.view === 'normal' ? '#ED4A56' : 'dodgerblue'
  let reviewed = 'black'
  let completed = 'gray'
  let started = 'yellow'

  let testDetails = [    
    {
      id: sample.labid,
      name: 'ac sa',
      field: 'statusacsa',
      status: sample.statusacsa,
      colorStatus: sample.statusacsa === 'reviewed' ? reviewed : sample.statusacsa === 'completed' ? completed : sample.statusacsa === 'started' ? started : sample.statusacsa === 'assigned' ? assigned : unassigned,
      colorNormal: sample.statusacsa === null || sample.statusacsa === '' ? unassigned : '#EDB84A' //orange
    },
    {
      id: sample.labid,
      name: 'av',
      field: 'statusav',
      status: sample.statusav,
      colorStatus: sample.statusav === 'reviewed' ? reviewed : sample.statusav === 'completed' ? completed : sample.statusav === 'started' ? started : sample.statusav === 'assigned' ? assigned : unassigned,
      colorNormal: sample.statusav === null || sample.statusav === '' ? unassigned : '#EDB84A' //orange
    }
  ]

  let i = 0
  let tests = testDetails.map((test) => {
    i++

    return(
      <Test key={i} test={test} view={props.view} isTodo={props.isTodo} onClick={props.onClick} />
    )
  })

  return (
    <span>
      {tests}      
    </span>
  )
}

export default AssignLab
```

Then finally Test re-renders:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Test = (props) => {

  // const style = {
  //   backgroundColor: props.view === 'normal' ? props.test.colorNormal : props.test.colorStatus,
  //   border: '1px solid black',
  //   borderRadius: 5,
  //   color: props.view === 'status' && (props.test.status === 'completed ' || props.test.status === 'reviewed') ? 'white' : 'black',
  //   display: props.isTodo && props.test.status !== 'assigned' && props.test.status !== 'started' ? 'none' : 'inline-block',
  //   margin: 5
  // }

  let style = {
    backgroundColor: props.view === 'normal' ? props.test.colorNormal : props.test.colorStatus,
    border: '1px solid black',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: props.view === 'status' && (props.test.status === 'completed ' || props.test.status === 'reviewed') ? 'white' : 'black',
    display: props.isTodo && props.test.status !== 'assigned' && props.test.status !== 'started' ? 'none' : 'inline-block',
    margin: 5
  }

  let style2 = {
    backgroundColor: props.view === 'normal' ? props.test.colorNormal : props.test.colorStatus,
    border: '2px solid red',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: props.view === 'status' && (props.test.status === 'completed ' || props.test.status === 'reviewed') ? 'white' : 'black',
    display: props.isTodo && props.test.status !== 'assigned' && props.test.status !== 'started' ? 'none' : 'inline-block',
    margin: 5
  }


let test = <button type='button' onClick={props.onClick} style={style} data-id={props.test.id} data-field={props.test.field} data-status={props.test.status}>{props.test.name}</button>

  if (props.test.name === 'ac sa' && props.test.id === 20234) {
    console.log('test data: ' + JSON.stringify(props.test))
    console.log('view: ' + props.view)
    console.log('style: ' + JSON.stringify(style))
  }



  return (
    (props.test.name === 'ac sa' && props.test.id === 20234 && props.test.status === 'assigned') ?
    <button type='button' onClick={props.onClick} style={style} data-id={props.test.id} data-field={props.test.field} data-status={props.test.status}>{JSON.stringify(style)}</button> :
    (props.test.name === 'ac sa' && props.test.id === 20234 && props.test.status === '') ?
    <button type='button' onClick={props.onClick} style={style2} data-id={props.test.id} data-field={props.test.field} data-status={props.test.status}>{JSON.stringify(style)}</button> :
    <button type='button' onClick={props.onClick} style={style} data-id={props.test.id} data-field={props.test.field} data-status={props.test.status}>{props.test.name}</button>
  )
}

export default Test
```

I have left my console.logs and ternaries in the Test component to show some of my efforts to solve this. Originally, I used a single let style={...} with a ternary in Test to change the backgroundColor of the button, but it will not change even if i update my hook state in App. My console.logs show that the style is updated with the correct color, but the button doesnt reflect it after render. However, if I put the style object in the button's display value...the button's display value updates with the color's name, yet not the backgroundColor. If I place a ternary in the return of Test and toggle between style and style2, the color does not update. Finally, if I place

```
style = {{backgroundColor: 'purple'}}
```

in place of

```
style={style}
```

within the ternary in the return of Test, it will change colors. Can something explain why React is not re-rending the backgroundColor when new props are passed down?

Also, if the test is initially 'unassigned' and I click it, it will change the backgroundColor from 'Gray' to 'Red, but if I click it again, it will not update. If I click a test which has been assigned and has a backgroundColor of 'Red' or other color, it will not change.